What bearing type for a evaporator fan in a refridgerator
I'm building a fridge and think I could use a fan to transport air over the evaporator. What I think I want is a 12VDC fan (because 12VDC is available), but what more considerations are there?
What I tried so far is using Sunon Fans HA80251V4-1000U-A99, but that failed rather quickly, it no longer moves when attached to 12V.
The environment in the fridge is somewhat cool. I've measured the evaporator to approx -10C (14F), so cooler that that there should be nowhere. Also there's water condensing.
What bearing type is appropriate for this environment?

If you are building the fan then consider oilite bushes or roller bearings - many types of bearings are used in 12V motors.

Buy a fan made for cars not computers.  No way you can design a better fan than Delco.
